# C# Exception Handling specific classes

Tags: c#, try-catch

What is the main advantage to have specific exception classes , as we can have all exceptions in System.Exception class.
Why would one use specific error handling class?

Comment: just came out of interview?

Comment: The answer really depends on your needs - sometimes you need things to be more granular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should we create our own java exception classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698584/when-should-we-create-our-own-java-exception-classes)

Comment: If you want to add specific structured information to your exception, a custom exception class allows you to add your own properties.  It also allows consuming code to catch specifically that exception if the logic requires.

Comment: no alex its not a duplicate questions.
Just wana know the fact that what is the use of specic exception classes such as IndexOutOfRangeException and ArgumentException

Comment: @farrukhmask: The linked potential duplicate question primarily answers exactly that.  Did you read it?

Comment: What is the main advantage to have classes at all, as we can have all objects as System.Object class? Why would one use specific classes at all? :)

Answer (score 1):

Exception handlers work on a class by class basis. If you only had one exception class, you couldn't do this:

```
try
{
    //Do something that might raise different types of exceptions
}
catch(ArgumentException e1)  //Catch any exception that is an ArgumentException or one its derived types
{
    //Do something to handle the invalid argument
}
catch(NetworkException e2)  //Catch any exception that is a NetworkException or one of its derived types
{
    //Do something to handle the issue with the network
}
catch(Exception e3)
{
    //Do something to log the unexpected exception
    throw;
}
```

Note that [you should not catch the base exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx) unless the only thing you are doing is logging it and rethrowing.