# REST API | Exception Handling | Identify Layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exception, model-view-controller

We are building multiple services using `springboot`. Need to understand the design about Exception handling. For now currently we are handling and trhowing Exception in service layer.

We have **Custom Exceptions in place**, and in few services we have `@ControllerAdvice` to handle exception globally.

In few service we *throw exception from Controller layer* also.

Need to undersatnd is it a good design to throw exception from controller layer, or shall we replace with some custom Error codes ?

These services can be used internally or hosted as well to be consued by 3rd party.

Comment: There is no rule where you can throw an exception. Throwing at the controller layer or the service layer is a team decision. I can say for myself that I never accept a merge request that throws exception in the controller layer. Theoretically, the controller shouldn't have any rules. The Service owns the data, so it is responsible for handling errors.

Answer (score 2):

The exceptions you throw from your service layer are should ideally be related to the business logic of your domain. For example you will maybe throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if someone wanted to update a `User` object that did not exist. In general you only want to throw *custom exceptions* "if they do have useful information for client code" (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22698673/16560836)).

If there are complications on the Controller layer, e.g., an invalid value provided by the client for a custom header, then you are perfectly fine throwing an exception in the controller layer, too.

As you have already mentioned, in general you then want to have one or more global exception handlers, which can convert the thrown Exceptions into a more useful http response for the client, probably in json format and with a proper HTTP Status Code (e.g., internal server error) and maybe a descriptive message. But you can also be more specific than that and return different http status code and payloads in different scenarios. For example, maybe in the case where someone wanted to update a user that did not exist you want to return a 404 status code. Check out the more flexible `ResponseEntity` return type for that.

Regarding error codes, you have to ask yourself if the client is benefiting from that or if they are more happy with a short message or do not care at all.